# Django filter on multiple many-to-many rows

Tags: django, many-to-many, django-filter, django-q

I'm pretty new to Django and I have a problem on filtering on many-to-many objects.
I have a many-to-many relationship

```
class Person(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

  def __unicode__(self):
      return self.name 
class Group(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
  members = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through='Membership')

  def __unicode__(self):
      return self.name
class Membership(models.Model):
  person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
  group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
  date_joined = models.DateField()
  invite_reason = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

I can filter on Persons that are related to One single group

```
persons=Person.objects.filter(Q(group__name='Group1'))
```

But what I want to achieve is to filter on Persons that are exactly in two groups.

Example:

- Person1 is in Group1
- Person2 is in Group1 and Group2.

The filter should only return Person2.

Any tips how to create a filter for this?

Comment: Do you want people in *any* two groups, or specifically group1 + group2?

Comment: @DanielRoseman No I don't want people in any of those groups. I want people that are assigned to those two groups or more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should do it ...

```
groups = ["Group1","Group2"]
persons = Person.objects.annotate(count=Count('name')).filter(count__gte=len(groups)).filter(reduce(operator.or_, (Q(group__name=x) for x in groups)))
```